# How to differentiate between different NSTrackingAreas

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, swift, cocoa

In my main NSWindow I have setup multiple tracking areas around different NSTextFields (represented below as 'obj')

```
var track: NSTrackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: obj.bounds, options: NSTrackingAreaOptions.MouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingAreaOptions.ActiveAlways | NSTrackingAreaOptions.CursorUpdate , owner: self, userInfo: nil)
    obj.addTrackingArea(track)
```

In the `override func mouseEntered(theEvent: NSEvent) { }` method I would like to be able to run a different block for each tracking area I have specified. How could I go about identifying each tracking area separately? What is a unique identifier for each area?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to use the `userInfo` field when you create the tracking area. For example, add a different `NSNumber` for each tracking area. The `NSEvent` object you receive has a `userInfo` property that will retrieve this object for you.

A possibly more elegant way is to subclass `NSTrackingArea` because `NSEvent` also has a `trackingArea` property.

Comment: How can I use the trackingArea property to see if it is one of the objects using an if statement?

Comment: What I was suggesting is that you subclass NSTracking area - say "MyTrackingArea" and add properties and a method to MyTrackingArea to do the specialized work. So for example you would say a = event.trackingArea as! MyTrackingArea and then a.process(...) where "process" is the new method you added. Then you do not need an if statement.